# How do I remove empty p tags with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The platform I'm building a website on produces empty `p` tags in wysiwyg mode. How can I take these out?

Something like this, perhaps...

`$("<p> </p>").remove();`

Although the code above does nothing.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The answer depends on what "empty" means. If the empty paragraphs are `<p></p>` then fireeyedboy's `p:empty` selector is the way to go. If there could be spaces or newlines or other such things then you'll probably want something like this:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length === 0)
        $this.remove();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7L4WZ/

FCKEditor (not sure about CKEditor or TinyMCE) likes to add `<p>&nbsp;</p>` to the HTML so you might need the above somewhat ugly approach.

Comment: This is a much better and more practical answer!

Answer (score 54):

Try:

`$( 'p:empty' ).remove();`

Comment: best and simple

Answer (score 3):

you can try this...

```
$([selector]).is(":empty")
```

it will return true if selector is empty..[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSMhv/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but I found this thread recently as I was looking to solve this issue as well.

I came up with a Vanilla JS solution here, which worked for me:

```
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p:empty');
for(var i = p.length - 1; i > -1; i-- ) {
    p[i].parentNode.removeChild(p[i]);
}
```

It basically does (exactly) what fireeyedboy suggested, but without jQuery.

It also appears to perform better than jQuery as well:
http://jsperf.com/remove-empty-elements-javascript-vs-jquery

Hope this helps!

Comment: querySelectorAll has the problem of not being supported by older browsers

Comment: Good point. I guess in that case, if you choose the vanilla route with querySelector, you can use a Polyfill to add older browser support.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone need this for WP site, so use these:

```
jQuery('p').each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if($this.html().replace(/\s| /g, '').length == 0)
            $this.remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "mu is too short",

I've tried your code It works but I need to wrap it in `jQuery(document).ready(function() {});`

The full code worked for me is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('p').each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0) {
            $this.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know why this happens, My jQuery/JS is not so good, I'm learning it ;).

Hope this help another person like me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Remove empty paragraphs with &nbsp; */
jQuery('p').each(function(){
    if( jQuery(this).html() == '&nbsp;' )
        jQuery(this).remove();
})
```