# remove <p> &nbsp;</p> with jquery if no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

how to hide attributes if detect this `<p> &nbsp;</p>`

My problem is when my client insert data(example table) with ckeditor , when i see the source code , ckeditor will add this `<p> &nbsp;</p>` after table code. i know how to remove this manualy with source code(open source code and delete) but not my client!

Comment: have you tried answer ? is it work for you ?

Comment: WYSIWYG editors do this so that when someone clicks on the bottom of the text editor it gives them an actual place to put their cursor.  Say if there's a table, the only other place to put the cursor would be inside of the table, and that's probably not what people want when using a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Orignal answer : [How do I remove empty p tags with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092855/how-do-i-remove-empty-p-tags-with-jquery)

Try

```
$('p').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
     $this.remove(); });
```

here is working code : http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7L4WZ/

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work. Pretty quick and hacky

```
$("p").each(function() { 
   var $el = $(this);
   if($.trim($el.html()) == "&nbsp;") {
     $el.remove();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var value = $.trim($(this).html());
    if(value == '&nbsp;'){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

this will work on all p tags so better to write selector with its parent tag, so it should not effect other page elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
     $this.remove(); });
```

This worked like a charm for me. Thank you Pranay!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').filter(function() {
 return trim($(this).text()) == "";
 }).remove();
```