# Remove emty option from select

Tags: jquery, html

I have this kind of HTML

```
<select id="SelectedCulture" name="SelectedCulture">
<option></option>
<option>en-US</option>
</select>
```

What i need in Jquery is to remove  that is empty?

Comment: You should research at least a bit before posting trivial questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove empty p tags with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092855/how-do-i-remove-empty-p-tags-with-jquery)

Comment: @aldanux It is very hard to finr on search because my criteria was select :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:empty` to check whether it is empty or not. Then use `remove()` to remove the element.

```
$("#SelectedCulture option:empty").remove();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/44gU9/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Go for this:

```
$("#SelectedCulture > option").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length==0)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6zY3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("option").each(function() {
    var text= $(this).text();
    if(text== '') { // or anything else you want to remove...
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

This will remove empty elements from that

**[Edit]**

still suggest to prefer Anoop Joshi's answer