# How to remove extra lines in paragraphs

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of info called from an api :

for example,

```
"

  1. Assist food and technology department in record keeping and filing"
```

how to remove the extra line ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove empty p tags with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092855/how-do-i-remove-empty-p-tags-with-jquery)

Comment: This question deserves a place in some hall of fame.

Comment: if you use jquery, method `$.trim()` is usefull

Comment: @Saeed I am using Typescript/Javascript.... I already tried `trim()` but it didn't work out..and I cannot use jQuery

Comment: Use this `string.replace(/\s+/g, '');`. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal, hey, your replace will remove all spaces... probably not exactly what he wants. It should probably be `[\r\n]+` and not `\s+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete all white space at the start and end of the string. This is what [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) does:

```js
s = `

  1. Assist food and technology department in record keeping and filing
  
  `;
s = s.trim();
console.log(s);
```

The alternative to `trim()` (if your browser does not support it?) would be a regular expression:

```js
s = '\n\n1. Assist food and technology department in record keeping and filing   \n \r\n   ';
s = s.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general there are 3 types of things that generate an unwanted new line:

- The newline `\n`
- The carriage return `\r`
- The `<br/>` tag

JavaScript supports regex with its `replace()` function:

```
s = s.replace(/[\r\n]+|<br *\/?>/g, " ");
```

**Note 1:** that I added a `?` after the `/` of the `<br/>` tag because many browser do not insert that character, so it is very likely not present.

**Note 2:** I put a space between whatever is before and after the newlines, this means words will still be separated as expected.

If you want to do a trim from the start and end of the string, you can use:

```
s = s.replace(/^(<br *\/?>| |\t|\n|\r|\v|\f|&nbsp;|&#160;|&#xA0;)+/, "")
     .replace(/(<br *\/?>| |\t|\n|\r|\v|\f|&nbsp;|&#160;|&#xA0;)+$/, "");
```

Note that `\s+` may or may not include all those character the way they appear in my regex. How things appear depend on the browser in use.